# Hi, have any of you managed to implement a bidirectional relationship in typeOrm with vanilla javaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeorm

I am trying to implement a two-way one-to-one relationship and can hardly find any information about it.

I only found this: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2997

I did my exercise following what I read in the post and it gives me an error when trying to join the entities, could someone help me?

I put them in context:
I have two entities: Vehicle and VehicleAttribute.

My task requires me that the entity 'VehicleAttribute' has the FK of the enity 'Vehicle', being a one-to-one relationship.

The problem is that an implementation of the typeOrm schemas is being made with Js vanilla (the decorators are not being implemented) and I need to be able to access the vehicle attributes with the queryBuilder, starting from the vehicle entity.

When trying to join with the queryBuilder, knowing that vehicle has an alias that is 'i', when compiling it gives me an error because it cannot join with a column that does not exist.

```
queryBuilder.innerJoinAndSelect('i.attributes',"attributes");
```

[vehicleSchema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VhBK.jpg)

[VehicleAttributeSchema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6MiP.jpg)

[ApiReturn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4wRJ.jpg)